# AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'next'

Tags: python, linked-list

```
    class Node(object):

        def __init__(self, data = None, next = None):
            self.data = data
            self.next_node = next

        def get_data(self):
            return self.data

        def get_next(self):
            return self.next_node

        def set_next(self, new_next):
            self.next_node = new_next

  class LinkedList(object):

    def __init__(self, head = None):
        self.head = head

    def insert(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data, None)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
        else:
            new_node.next = self.head
            self.head = new_node

          def print_list(self):
                    temp = self.head
                    while temp!=None:
                        print(temp.data)
                        if temp.next != None:
                           temp = temp.next
s = LinkedList()
s.insert(3)
s.insert(4)
s.insert(5)
s.insert(6)
  s.print_list()
```

I always get this Node object has no attribute next in the console. It prints the linkedlist but how do I get rid of that warning. What extra condition should I put?

Comment: Show us the definition of `class Node`

Answer (score 5):

In `LinkedList`, you keep accessing the node’s next node using the property name `next` but in the `Node` type, you actually defined the next pointer to be called `next_node`.

So either change the `Node` definition so the pointer is just called `next`, or change the usages in `LinkedList` to refer to `node.next_node` instead of just `node.next`